# Remove the last x% of rows in each df, in a list of dfs, dependent upon a numeric vector

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

I have a list of dataframes where each dataframe contains the same number of rows. I have a numeric vector (`removal`) that specifies how much I want to remove from each dataframe (e.g., remove the last 25% from the first df, `df1`).

I can keep the first x% of rows from each df by creating a function and using `lapply`, but I don't know how to incorporate that code into a loop that would loop through `removal`. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(var = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(var = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE))
df3 <- data.frame(var = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE))
lst <- list(df1, df2, df3)

head(df1)
#>   var
#> 1   3
#> 2   2
#> 3   2
#> 4   4
#> 5   5
#> 6   2

removal <- c(.25, .30, .50)
# I want to remove the last 25% of rows from df1,
# the last 30% of rows from df2,
# and the last 50% of rows from df3

# I can only make it so I can keep a static percentage from each df
# from the top of each df
# but I don't know to incorporate this code with a loop
# that would loop through `removal`
fake_removal <- .75

fake_remv <- function(x){
  x <- x %>% filter(row_number() < nrow(x) * fake_removal) 
  return(x)
  }

badlst <- lapply(lst, fake_remv)
print(nrow(badlst[[1]]))
#> [1] 74
head(badlst[[1]])
#>   var
#> 1   3
#> 2   2
#> 3   2
#> 4   4
#> 5   5
#> 6   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `Map/mapply` in `base R` or `map2` from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map2(lst, removal, ~ .x %>% 
        filter(row_number() < nrow(.x) * .y))
```

The equivalent `Map` option would be

```
Map(function(dat, rml) subset(dat, seq_len(nrow(dat)) < nrow(dat) * rml),
         lst, removal)
```